# Plot the output of DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, inverse-function

I need to plot the output of DSolve.  How should I proceed?

`{{a[t] -> InverseFunction[E^(2 C[1])ArcTanh[Sqrt[#1]/Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1]] -  Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1] &][t]}`

We can set E^{2C[1]} to one for now for simplicity.

Comment: See documentation for `DSolve` > Scope > Basic Uses > 4th example. (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

Answer (score 3):

For `C[1]=1`

```
sol = InverseFunction[
    E^(2 C[1]) ArcTanh[Sqrt[#1]/Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1]] - 
      Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1] &][t] /. C[1] -> 1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is complex valued. So you can only plot the real part or the imaginary part or absolute value.

```
 Plot[Re[sol/.t->tt],{tt,-10,10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Im[sol /. t -> tt], {tt, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Abs[sol/.t->tt],{tt,-10,10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use

```
ReImPlot[sol/.t->tt,{tt,-10,10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Let us assign the solution to a variable first to make it easier to use:

```
sol = {a[t] -> InverseFunction[E^(2 C[1])ArcTanh[Sqrt[#1]/Sqrt[E^(2 C[1])
       + #1]] -  Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1] &][t]}
```

You can directly assign this value from the `DSolve` expression as well as in:

```
sol = DSolve[ ... ]
```

Note that there was a stray `{` in the code provided. Note that if your solution consists of multiple lists of `a[t]` values, this may become a little more complicated but the overall idea should remain the same.

Now `Plot` the solved for function with the given information (`C[1] -> 0`, which makes the exponential term as a whole go to 1):

```
Plot[a[t] /. (sol /. C[1]->0), {t, -10, 10}]
```

Note that we substitute in `C[1]->0` into the solution *first* and then use that solution to get `a[t]`. Also note that due to the naming `a[t]` in the pattern in `sol` that we cannot use some other variable without going through some additional substitutions.

The graph disappears at $t=0$. Examining a[1] requires us to use those additional substitutions, but quickly reveals what's going on:

```
(a[t] /. (sol /. C[1] -> 0)) /. t -> 1
```

> -0.868... - 0.847... I

In both cases I use a pretty specific order of substitution that in my experience works most reliably with these sorts of solution sets. The most important matter here is that if the substitution `t->1` affects the group `C[1] -> 0`, then it won't do anything because there's no `t` in that group. It needs to catch all of the `t` values we need to substitute, so it needs to go on the outermost side.

In any case, the reason the graph disappears at $t=0$ is because for positive $t$ values the function has an imaginary component. We can split that out as follows:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Re[a[t]], Im[a[t]]} /. (sol /. (C[1] -> 0))],
     {t, -10, 10}]
```

The use of `Evaluate` here causes the table to get split up before it gets to `Plot`, so the lines have different colors. It is not strictly necessary otherwise. `Re` and `Im` grab the real and imaginary components.

It is possible that your full solution set has at least 1 or 2 other possible `a[t]` functions, since this looks similar to how a quadratic or a cubic would split around the roots of unity. If so, one of them may be real for some or all positive $t$ values.